# how to create an interface like facebook/loopt

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make an application that have the looks of

[image]

or

[image]

How can I do it in iphone using objective-C? Is it just a view that has a bunch of images?

I was just wondering why only loopt and facebook uses these kind of view, while other such as foursquare, twitter, gowalla, etc.. doesn't use it? Is it because these kinds of views are hard to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and straightforward way would be to have a background image that has all the button images and the just overlay square-ish buttons. (Quick 'n nasty).

If you want a more proper approach (and to be able to add the wiggling effect) then you're going to have to have distinct buttons with custom views (the actual images).

Notice that both apps use a UIScrollView to lay each page into. So from a hierarchical perspective you have:
navigationController.view -> UIScrollView -> UIView (container for each page) -> UIButton (with custom views done using UIImageViews) and optionally UILabels underneath each UIButton

Comment: so those buttons goes into the UIScrollView and when I click on it, then it redirects it to a specific UIView?

Comment: When you click a button you just push a new view controller that corresponds to the right action.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do it in iphone using objective-C? Is it just a view that has a bunch of images?

basically — yes.

But at least the Facebook App was made using [Three20](http://three20.info/).

Comment: I don't understand on how Three20 could help